# Ways to fix unusual grouping of rests in Abjad?

Tags: python, arrays

Using Abjad, I'm trying to create random combinations of 4th, 8th, and 16th notes and rests.  The notation does not read well. I think because of the unusual grouping of rests. For example, two consecutive 8th rests should be a quarter rest. An 8th and a 16th rest should be a dotted 8th rest, etc. Looking for suggestions on how I can fix this odd notation?

Here is example output
[image: Here is example output]

```
import random
import abjad

def random_notes():
    noteDuration = [4, 8, 16]
    beatCount = 0. # Keep track of how much space is left in a beat

    returnArray = []

    while beatCount < 1:
        validNoteValueFound = False
        noteVal = 0
        dur = 0
        while not validNoteValueFound:
            dur = random.randrange(0, 3)
            noteVal = 1. / noteDuration[dur]
            remainingSpace = 1. - beatCount
            if noteVal <= remainingSpace:
                # if note fits
                validNoteValueFound = True

        returnArray.append(noteType() + str(noteDuration[dur]))
        beatCount += noteVal

    return " ".join(returnArray)

def noteType():
    if random.randrange(0, 2) == 1:
        return "c"
    else:
        return "r"
def generateMeasures(numberOfMeasures):
    measures = []
    for i in range(0, numberOfMeasures):
        measures.append(random_notes())

    return "".join(flattenStringArray(measures))


def flattenList(list):
    flattenedList = []
    for i in list:
        for j in i:
            flattenedList.append(j)

    return flattenedList

def flattenStringArray(stringArr):
    return "".join(stringArr)

# Display randomly generated measures
staff = abjad.Staff(generateMeasures(10), lilypond_type="RhythmicStaff")
abjad.show(staff)
```

My goal is to have the notation be more legible. Currently the groupings make the notation very hard to read.

My two ideas are to keep track of the previously and current generated rest, simplify if possible. Or allow groupings to be generated as is, then after they've been generated check to see if simplifications exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is just sum the duration of *all* consecutive rests and replace them with a better representation. So if you want to do it at generation time you will need to wait until you meet a note, or the bar end.

The simplest approach would mean that for instance, in the first bar in your example, you have a 1/2 rest followed by a 1/8 one; in the second bar, you would have a 1/4 rest at the beginning, and a 1/2 plus 1/16 later. But you may want to try and realign to quarter beats, so the "best" representation may vary depending on where the rest is in the bar.